# Getting java args into a Arraylist wont work

Tags: java

i´m almost freaking out because of the following problem:

```
public class FileMate {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Walker walker = new Walker();

      int mode = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      Checker.mode = mode;

      List<String> drives = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (int i=1; i == args.length; i++) {
         drives.add(args[i]+":\\");
      }

      for (String path : drives) {
         walker.walk(path);
      }
   }
}
```

The first argument is an integer and gets succesfully assigned to "mode".
But the part where the drive letters should be assigned to the list "drives" getting skipped at runtime.
I already debugged it step by step and the args array contains the mode and the 2 drive letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `for` loop condition must be `true` for the loop to run, not for it to stop.  Change your condition to:

```
i < args.length
```

Incidentally, you may want to check the length of the `args` array before you start accessing it, just in case the user didn't provide any arguments.